# Flyway - Multiple DBs with Central Migration

Tags: flyway

Our company has about 30+ applications written in different languages (java, c#, visual basic, nodejs etc)

Our aim is to have development teams keep the database change sqls in their repositories, and do the migration from Jenkins with them starting pipelines with version number. Development teams don't have access to Jenkins configuration, they can only run jobs that we created and configured.

How should we go about this? Do we have too keep different flyway instances for each application? And how about pre-production and production stages?

Basically, how should we, as devops team, maintain flyway to do migration of different applications with different stages, without the development teams doing the migration part.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible with the Flyway CLI. You can tell Flywyay where to look for migrations and how to connect to the database. [See the docs about configuring the CLI](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/#configuration).

You can configure Flyway in various ways - environment variables, command line arguments, and config files.

What you could do is allow each development team to specify a migrations directory and connection details for the Jenkins task. The task can then call the Flyway CLI, overriding the relevant config items via command line arguments. For example, the command line call to migrate a database:

```
flyway url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//<host>:<port>/<service> -locations=some-location migrate
```

Or you could allow your devs to specify environment variables, or provide a custom config file.

You can reuse a single Flyway instance since the commands are essentially stateless. The only bit of environmental state they need comes from the config file, which you have complete control over.

Hope that helps